# Alamofire request when app in background

Tags: ios, json, swift, background, alamofire

Hi I want to fetch some data using Alamofire and a `NSTimer`

The app works fine on foreground, the timer is set to call the `GetEstado` function each 30 seconds but when the app enters background the timer is paused and if my server updates something it does not actually updates on the app

Here's my code

```
func GetEstado(){
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://myurl/getestado.php", parameters: ["id": id])
        .responseString { rta in
            if let dataFromString = rta.result.value!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
                for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
                    if(key=="e"){
                        if(subJson.stringValue=="1"){
                            self.Timer.invalidate()
                            print("ACTUALIZACION")
                            let notification = UILocalNotification()
                            notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
                            notification.alertBody = "UPDATED"
                            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
                            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("UPDATED", sender: self)
                        }
                        else{
                            print("UPS")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use NSTimer when your app is in the background because execution is suspended. You can use background fetch but this will only execute every few hours at most. You can also use push messaging from your server. Polling in the way you are is very inefficient in terms of bandwidth and battery power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Paulw11 answer your question in his comment, you can't use `NSTimer` in background, Apple has a known list of the task that can be produced in background, you can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

But let think for a moment what you're trying to achieve, let suppose you can do it using `NSTimer`, then you have your app in background consuming memory and battery in your device constantly to try to get the updates from your server, this is not recommended at all.

It's for this that Apple/Google introduced Apple Push Notifications (Google: Android Push Notifications) to handle that the server notifies the app when it's in background or inactive regarding any task that is programmed in the server, lets say a new mail, a new message in the case of messaging apps, etc.

Then, the option you have is use the service proposed by Apple, you can read more in the following docs:

- [Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/)
- [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

I hope this help you.